# Disable Kendo Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, kendo-ui

I have this Kendo Autocomplete code:

HTML:

```
<input id="faceUsers" type="text" placeholder="Search..." data-role="autocomplete" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false"  aria-autocomplete="list" aria-busy="false">
```

JS:

```
 $("#faceUsers").kendoAutoComplete({
                            dataTextField: "name",
                            dataValueField: "name",
                            template: '<img src=\"${data.picture.data.url}\" class="imguser" />' +
                                    '<h4 class="autotext">${ data.name }</h4>',                               
                            filter: "contains",
                            minLength: 1,
                            height: 370,
                            dataSource: faceDataSource
        });
```

I have set properly my `faceDataSource` and it works as expected.

The problem i am facing is how i can disable this autocomplete. After a particular action i want the `input` element to behave as a normal `input` element without autocomplete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to completely remove it, use [destroy](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/autocomplete):

```
$("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete();
var autocomplete = $("#autocomplete").data("kendoAutoComplete");
autocomplete.destroy();
```

Answer (score 2):

For your Better Reference just have a look to :: [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/krustev/fzDpv/)

As you can see in the Demo example link above the property of `suggest` into autocomplete is set to `on/off` as::

```
var autocomplete = $("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
    suggest: true,
    dataSource: ["Item1", "2Item"]             
}).data("kendoAutoComplete");

And also have a look to
```

http://www.telerik.com/forums/turn-off-on-stop-and-start-autocomplete-and-suggest-after-init

Answer (score 0):

Another point of view. We can able to do autocomplete as read only if we want to disable the editing.

```
var sampledd= $("#dd").data("kendoAutoComplete"); 
sampledd.readonly(false);
```

Disable Suggest

```
sampledd.suggest(true); // this one causing issue in IE
```