# Kendo Grid, how to disable autocomplete and filter icon in search input above column and process request after enter is pushed?

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid, filtering

I would like to disable native behaviour on selected column in kendo grid.

**First thing:**

I would like to disable default "autocomplete" behaviour for searching input and i would like to process remote read request only if whole number is given into input and enter key is pushed. And i would like to set custom operator for this column.

**Second thing**

I would like to remove filtering icon (see attached image), because there is not needed (i want to get only one row with equal given number or nothing).

[image]
I tried to do this by this way, but without luck:

```
if(value.filterable.cell.dataTextField == "orderNumber") {
            preparedGridColumnItem.filterable = {
              extra: false,

            }
          }
```

How can i solve it please?

Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

At first, to disable autocomplete (depends on column data type) you can define your own filterable element:

```
{
    field: "Title",
    filterable: {
        ui: titleFilter
    }
},


function titleFilter(element) {
    element.addClass("k-input");
}
```

For second question (referring to http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.filterable.cell.showOperators) you should showOperators option:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
  {
    field: "name",
    filterable: {
      cell: {
        showOperators: false,
        operator: "contains"
      }
    }
  },
  { field: "age" } ],
  filterable: { mode: "row" },
  dataSource: [ { name: "Jane", age: 30 }, { name: "John", age: 33 }] 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but first part of your answer is not working for me. titleFilter element is undefined.

Comment: `titleFilter` is a function defined in scope. Try anonymouse function: `... filterable: {
        ui: function(element) {
    element.addClass("k-input");
}
    } ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this:
[Disable Kendo Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22477877/disable-kendo-autocomplete)
or you can simply enable/disable your autocomplete. Read this: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete/configuration/enable

Answer (score 0):

Define your own filterable element like this

```
{
    field: "Title",
    filterable: {
        ui: noAutoFilter
    }
}
```

Disable the kendoautocomplete server filtering using the attributes below

```
var noAutoFilter = {
    template: function (e) {
        e.element.kendoAutoComplete({
            serverFiltering: false,
            valuePrimitive: true,
            noDataTemplate: ''
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For kendo grid cell editing if you want to off chrome autofill options try below code
call this function on your kendo grid edit

function GridOnCellEdit(e) {
//Take each column. In our case we have three columns length, width and height.
    var filterLength = e.container.find('input[name="Length"]');
    var filterWidth = e.container.find('input[name="Width"]');
    var filterHeight = e.container.find('input[name="Height"]');

    //Disable autocomplete for respective columns when user try to edit
    if (filterLength != null && filterLength[0] != null) {
        filterLength[0].autocomplete = "off";
    }
    if (filterWidth != null && filterWidth[0] != null) {
        filterWidth[0].autocomplete = "off";
    }
    if (filterHeight != null && filterHeight[0] != null) {
        filterHeight[0].autocomplete = "off";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in main toolbar.Search(), on every page loading k.input autocomplete with my login.
I solved this problem with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
        $("input.k-input").attr("autocomplete", "new-password"); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

for disable auto complete for specific column , can do this:

```
filterable: {
   cell: {
           dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: [] }),
           operator: "eq"
       }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In 2022 ui appears be obsolete.

Here are an example that currently works fine.

First, create a new variable with parameters (with template):

```
var noAutoFilter = {
operator: "contains",
suggestionOperator: "contains",
template: function (e) {
    e.element.kendoAutoComplete({
        serverFiltering: false,
        valuePrimitive: true,
        noDataTemplate: ''
    });
}
```

}

Then in your columns use it:

```
{ field: "ProductName", title: "Product", width: 180, filterable: { cell: noServerFilterAuto } }
```

That's it.

Source: https://www.telerik.com/forums/turning-off-autocomplete-on-column-filtering

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)